# What is the meaning of the nameless lady's words to Baroness Joy von Troken?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-princess-diaries

In **[The Princess Diaries (2001)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0247638/)**, what is the meaning of the nameless lady's words to Baroness Joy Von Troken after declaring Mia as Princess?

> **Nameless Lady:** I hope you didn't order your stationary yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I recall, if Mia didn't accept her position as Princess of Genovia, the Baroness would likely have been next in line to become Queen after Clarisse was no longer able to rule. For some time toward the end of the movie, it looked like Mia was not going to accept her princessship (that should be a word), implying that the Baroness thought she was quite likely to become Queen. Of course, given that Mia *does* decide to become a proper princess, anything the Baroness may have done in preparation for ascending to the throne herself (such as ordering custom stationery with her name and presumed title, as a power-hungry and egotistical character might do) will have gone to waste.

In case you are a non-native/non-fluent English speaker, I'll clarify that the nameless lady probably does not *literally* believe the Baroness has ordered custom stationery. It's more a way of expressing cruel satisfaction that the Baroness will not be taking on the title of Queen.